# Merging 3 Functions together

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to merge these 3 functions together so I can get all my data into stream and it will show up in the individual div. How would I go about this?

AJAX It won't get the users first, middle or last name as that is returned under response.users not response.stream

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{
$('.load_more').live("click",function() 
{
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
if(ID)
{
$("#load"+ID).html('Loading...');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "include/load_more_home_posts.php",
cache: false, 
dataType: "json",
data: { streamitem_id: ID},
cache: false,
success: function(response){
     $.each(response.streams, function(i, stream) {
    $("#articles").prepend("<div id='divider-"+stream['streamitem_id']+"'><div class='userinfo'><a href='/profile.php?username="+stream['username']+"'><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped"+stream['id']+".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a><div class'delete' style='cursor:pointer;position:relative;top:0px;float:right;padding-right:5px;' onclick=\"delete_('"+stream['streamitem_id']+"');\">X</div><a href='/profile.php?username="+stream['username']+"'>"+stream['first']+" "+ stream['middle']+" "+stream['last']+"</a><span class='subtleLink'> said</span><br/><a class='subtleLink' style='font-weight:normal;'>"+stream['streamitem_timestamp']+"</a><hr>"+stream['streamitem_content']+"<div style='height:20px;' class='post_contextoptions'><div id='streamcomment'><a style='cursor:pointer;' id='commenttoggle_"+stream['streamitem_id']+"' onclick=\"toggle_comments('comment_holder_"+stream['streamitem_id']+"');clearTimeout(streamloop);swapcommentlabel(this.id);\">Write a comment...</a></div><div id='streamlike'><a title='Like "+stream['first']+" "+ stream['middle']+" "+stream['last']+"s status' id='likecontext_"+stream['streamitem_id']+"' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"likestatus("+stream['streamitem_id']+",this.id);\"><div style='width:50px;' id='likesprint"+stream['streamitem_id']+"'>Like</a></div><div style='width:50px;' id='likesprint"+stream['streamitem_id']+"'><a title='See who likes "+stream['first']+" "+ stream['middle']+" "+stream['last']+"s status' href='include/likes.php?streamitem_id="+stream['streamitem_id']+"' /></a></div></div></form></div><div id='streamdislike'><a id='dislikecontext_"+stream['streamitem_id']+"' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"dislikestatus("+stream['streamitem_id']+",this.id);\"><div style='width:70px;' id='dislikesprint"+stream['streamitem_id']+"'>Dislike</a></div><div style='width:70px;' id='dislikesprint"+stream['streamitem_id']+"'></div></div></form><div class='stream_comment_holder' style='display:none;' id='comment_holder_"+stream['streamitem_id']+"'><div id='comment_list_"+stream['streamitem_id']+"'></div><div class='stream_comment_inputarea'><form id='mycommentform' method='POST'  class='form_statusinput'>\
<input type='hidden'  name='streamidcontent' id='streamidcontent' value='"+stream['streamitem_id']+"'>\
<input type='input' name='commentingcontents' id='commentingcontents' placeholder='Say something' autocomplete='off'>\
<input type='submit' id='button' value='Feed'><br/></div></div>").show();

      // the rest of your code from inside your $.each() here
   });
};


  // Comments
    $.each(response.comments, function(i, comment) {

    });

 // Users
    $.each(response.users, function(i, user) {    
    });

// remove the previous load more link
$("#load"+ID).remove();
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

I need the 3 json objects that are sent back to all be inside 1 div so I get no UNDEFINED.

```
$following_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['id']);
$call="SELECT * FROM streamdata WHERE streamitem_id < '$lastID' AND streamitem_target=".$following_string." OR streamitem_creator=".$following_string." ORDER BY streamitem_id DESC LIMIT 10";
$chant = mysqli_query($mysqli, $call) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$json = array();
$json['streams'] = array();

while ($resultArr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chant)) {
    $arr = array();
    $arr['streamitem_id'] = $resultArr['streamitem_id'];
    $arr['streamitem_content'] = $resultArr['streamitem_content'];
    $arr['streamitem_timestamp'] = Agotime($resultArr['streamitem_timestamp']);

    $json['streams'][] = $arr;
}

/***** COMMENTS *****/
$check = "SELECT comment_id, comment_datetime, comment_streamitem, comment_poster, comment_content FROM streamdata_comments WHERE comment_poster=".$following_string."  ORDER BY comment_datetime DESC";
$check1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
$json['comments'] = array();

while ($resultArr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check1)) {
    $arr = array();
    $arr['comment_id'] = $resultArr['comment_id'];
    $arr['comment_content'] = $resultArr['comment_content'];
    $arr['comment_poster'] = $resultArr['comment_poster'];
    $arr['comment_datetime'] = Agotime($resultArr['comment_datetime']);
    $arr['comment_streamitem'] = $resultArr['comment_streamitem'];

    $json['comments'][] = $arr;
}

/***** USERS *****/

$check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$following_string."";
$check1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
$json['users'] = array();

while ($resultArr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check1)) {
    $arr = array();
    $arr['username'] = $resultArr['username'];
    $arr['id'] = $resultArr['id'];
    $arr['first'] = $resultArr['first'];
    $arr['middle'] = $resultArr['middle'];
    $arr['last'] = $resultArr['last'];

    $json['users'][] = $arr;
}


echo json_encode($json);
}
?>
```

Comment: what JSON objects? more details, in current form your question cannot be answered.

Comment: My apologies. I meant these 3 functions. How would I merge them together?

Comment: what do you mean by merging them together?

Comment: Well.. My issue is. I have JSON in my php sperated into streams, comments and users..And when it comes back I was told to do the above. But the users name and the comments show as undefined within the div and I need to know how to do this. Maybe I thought merging the three would work. Could I provide you with the rest of my code so you understand.

Comment: If it does'nt work like that, it won't work any other way either. You're JSON boject is either not a JSON object, or you're trying to access values in that object that does'nt exist. Show us the JSON, or how you create and send the JSON on the serverside, and we will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I've provided my php code with the JSON.

Comment: Try something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/aLLT2/) ??

Comment: I've updated with my PHP page and my whole AJAX. I need it all in one div which is #articles. But obviously the first, middle and last name comes back under response.users. So how do I go about joining them.. It confuses me.

Comment: You'll of course have to put the data into elements in the DOM by setting the strings returned in your ajax as the content of the elements. You can use append(), prepend(), html() etc. You don't really have to join it all togehter in your script, but you could do that as well by just concentenating the values to a string, or creating an array. This is pretty basic stuff!

Comment: Which way would you choose as the best or easiest solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is convert your `comments` and `users` data into a format where you can easy look up the comments and users relating to your streams. As it is now, you would have to loop through each comment object in `comments` to find the comments that relate to your stream, then through each user in `users` to find a user which relates to your comment. This is not only horribly inefficient but code intensive.

To solve this, instead of sending flat arrays in your JSON, you should send objects with keys to aid you in looking things up. In other words, instead of your JSON looking like this:

```
{
    "streams": [...],
    "comments": [...],
    "users": [...]
}
```

It should look more like this:

```
{
    "streams": [...],
    "comments": {
        943: [...], /* 943 is the ID of the stream */
        945: [...],
        975: [...],
    },
    "users": {
        34: { ... }, /* these keys are user IDs */
        45: { ... },
        398: { ... },
    },
}
```

Or even embed your comments in the stream objects that they relate to:

```
{
    "streams": [
        { 
            ...,
            "comments": [...]
        },
        { 
            ...,
            "comments": [...]
        },
    ],
    "users": {
        34: { ... }, 
        45: { ... },
        398: { ... },
    },
}
```

With these structures, it's much easier to find the data you need while you're processing your streams.

It's best if your PHP produces the data in this more ideal format. I'm not a PHP expert, so I'll show you how you'd transform the data in your JavaScript. Before looping through your stream objects, preprocess your other arrays so that data lookup is easier:

```
var commentLookup = {};
var userLookup = {};

$.each(response.comments, function(i, comment) {
    var streamId = comment.comment_streamitem;
    if (!(streamId in commentLookup)) {
        commentLookup[streamId] = [];
    }
    commentLookup[streamId].push(comment);
});

$.each(response.users, function(i, user) {
    userLookup[user.id] = user;
});
```

Now when you're looping through your streams, you can easily look up your related objects:

```
$.each(response.streams, function(i, stream) {

    // Output stream content

    // Output comments
    $.each(commentLookup[stream.streamitem_id], function(i, comment) {
        // Output comment contents

        var commenter = userLookup[comment.comment_poster];
        var name = commenter.first + ' ' + commenter.last;
        // etc.
    });

});
```

Comment: This seems complex just to get 10 more statuses from the database. Isn't their anyway I can merge all the arrays into the variable $json when echoing it out through json_encode($json);

Comment: Yes. Like I said, it's more ideal if you merge your data server-side. You could change your SQL query to join your data, or you could build your lookup structures in your PHP. I'm not a PHP developer, so I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Yes I think I'll look into INNER JOINING the comments and users to the streamdata query. Thanks.